# What does the argument newline='' do in the open function?

Tags: python

I was learning Python in Codecademy and they were talking about using the `open()` function for CSV files. I couldn't really understand what the argument `newline=''` meant for the code.

```
import csv

with open('addresses.csv', newline='') as addresses_csv:
  address_reader = csv.DictReader(addresses_csv, delimiter=';')
  for row in address_reader:
    print(row['Address'])
```

Comment: Try typing `pydoc open`. Or just [read the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) online.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow!  The `help` function really, well, helps.  Try running `help(open)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your `csv.DictReader` function, you are iterating over lines in `addresses.csv` and mapping each row to a `dict`. Check the quoted fields in the `csv` file, and see if there are any escape sequences for ending a line `'\r\n'` - notice what happens when you include the `newline` parameter as shown in your code versus when you don't. Not including the `newline` parameter will probably add an extra line ending which you don't want. Including the `newline` parameter allows the csv module to handle the line endings itself - replicating the format as defined in your csv.

Answer (score 5):

I see the question has been answered already, but here's a good summary for the usage of the *newline* argument.

According to the [official csv documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples), it is recommended to open the file with the `newline=''` argument value on all platforms to disable universal newline translation. Universal newline is a manner of interpreting text streams in which all of the following are recognized as ending a line: the Unix convention, `'\n'`, the Windows convention, `'\r\n'`, and the old Macintosh convention, `'\r'`.

The *newline* argument in the `open()` function controls how newlines translations work. This argument can take any of the following values: `None`, `''`, `'\n'`, `'\r'`, `'\r\n'`. According to the [official python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), it works as follows:

> When reading the input from the stream (that is, when the mode of
> opening from the `open()` function is `'r'`), if newline is `None`
> (default value), universal newlines mode is enabled. That is, any
> of the following strings in the input are interpreted as newlines
> and translated to `'\n'` before the `open()` function returns. If
> it is `''`, universal newline mode is enabled still, but line
> endings are returned untranslated when the caller returns. If it has
> any of        the other values, input lines are only terminated by the
> given string, and the     line ending is returned to the caller
> untranslated.

> When writing output to the stream, if newline is `None`, any `'\n'`
> characters written are translated to the system default line
> separator (i.e. os.linesep, which is a string value of the following:
> `'\r'`, `'\n'`, `'\r\n'`, according to the os used). If newline is
> set to `''` or `'\n'`, no translation takes place. If newline is any
> of the other values, any `'\n'` characters written are translated to
> the given value. This mentions only the translation of `'\n'`. If we
> have `'\r'` in the output to the stream, it stays untranslated.

The reason why the csv documentation recommends opening a file with `newline=''` is because the csv writer terminates each line with a `\r\n` as mentioned in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator).
Now, on Windows, when writing to the stream using the `open()` function, if the value is `None`, at the ending of a line, the `\r` stays as it is while `\n` gets translated to `\r\n` according to the writing output to the stream section above. This means that a text like:

```
Line one
Line two
```

is in the form: `'Line one\r\r\nLine two\r\r\n'`.
The issue with this is that when reading the file again, assuming no argument is given to newline, it defaults to `None` and translates both `\r` and `\r\n` as new lines. The reason why opening a csv file with this form shows double lines is probably because the program you are opening it from (excel, notepad, etc.) has newline translation handling similar to that of the `open()` function and takes both `\r` and `\r\n` as newlines.

You can try and check yourself by creating csv without specifying the newline argument so that newlines are printed as `\r\r\n`:

```
with open('path\to\csv_file.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['row', 'one'])
    writer.writerow(['row', 'two'])
```

then reading the file without newline argument:

```
with open("path\to\csv_file.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f) 
    for row in reader: 
        print(row)
```

Output:

```
['row', 'one']
[]
['row', 'two']
[]
```

While with newline argument as `'\r\n'` on reading, you get the output:

```
['row', 'one']
['row', 'two']
```

In the first case, first Python reads the first line till before `\r` and creates a list from the data that was before this character and then creates a new line. But then before any other data, it encounters another newline character: `\r\n`, so it creates another list, but this list is empty since there was no data in between the two newline characters and the algorithm continues. On the second case, it reads `\r\n` only as an indication for a newline.

Answer (score 2):

minor difference recognising newline on unix and windows ('\n' vs '\r\n')

Lets consider the file 'text.txt' with below content (in windows)

```
cat text.txt
welcome
to
stackoverflow
```

Default newline in windows is '\r\n'
Now when you are reading file the default newline here '\r\n' in windows would convert to '\n'(universal mode)

```
>>>with open('text.txt','rt') as f: #Note Console (not using print(f.read())
     f.read()
#output 
'welcome\nto\nstackoverflow'
```

Now newline argument comes into picture for open()
By default newline is None for this reason above you see '\r\n' convert to '\n'

if this you do not need to convert to universal mode('\n') than you use newline='' for open

```
with open('text.txt','rt',newline='') as f:
    f.read()  
#output 
'welcome\r\nto\r\nstackoverflow'  (now 'r\n' not '\n')
```

Also newline can only be None or ''